# Weird modeling issue (possibly bone weighting?)

Tags: modeling, weight-painting

So I'm working on a custom avatar for a friend of mine for a game called VRChat. I've put the model into blender, configured all the bones and mesh. Weighted it all accordingly. Here's the issue i'm facing. I have the model right here:

[image]

And it looks good. No real big glaring issues. Still a few things I wanna touch up, but nothing too bad right now.

However, when I export it as an FBX and put it in Unity and go to configure the bones, this happens:

[image]

A random spike pops out of her wrist. I thought that maybe it wasn't anything to worry about, so I proceeded with putting it into VRChat. Well, that didn't work. The spike is still sticking out of her wrist. Does anyone know how I could go about fixing this?

Comment: Please use the editor tools to post images (free, easy, embedded) to help readers...

Comment: Fixed it. Hope that's better.

Comment: it could be some weight weirdness, but the only way to know if looking at weights, in that case... can't be spotted by above images...